# French visa for spouse (Talent)

Tags: france, family

I am an Indian national, planning to apply for a Talent visa to join a postdoctoral position in France. My wife is also planning to accompanying me. She has just completed M.Sc.

My specific question is, under what visa category should she apply ? Is it "family reunion or private settlement" or "mobility researcher/Talent" or some other more appropriate category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She should appy for a “[passeport talent (famille)](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F35792)” visa. If you don't find exactly this category in a form somewhere, I would simply look for “passeport talent” for her too.

She wouldn't want to apply for “regroupement familial” because additional requirement and paperwork would apply and, as a *passeport talent* visa holder your wife is exempt from it (that's one of the perks of your visa).